# How to show just notification count on appview android

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm new to android. And to show notification on android phones I got this below code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0  /*Request code*/ , intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mytune_default)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        int m = (int) ((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        notificationManager.notify(m  /*ID of notification*/ , notificationBuilder.build());
```

But the thing is I just want that notification unread count on code appview on system, but dont want other things loke message, title etc that appear on notification tray of system. How come this be acheived>

Comment: loke? Also I don't really understand what you are trying to ask.

Comment: I just want to show that notification count on appview but dont want to show message on notification bar on phone

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to replace launcher icon with widget. You can say to user to place your widget on the home screen, but not in application list. Users must do that in their own. Nevertheless, it's iOs pattern. It's not good idea to bring iOS design elements to android. Android have great notification bar, where user expect to see notification from your app. Android users don't expect to see it over the icon.

Comment: but when I use above code its showing notification both on app icon and notification bar

Comment: Can I show notification only in app icon but not in notification bar

Comment: No.thats not possible.